# How to make my <li> listing overlap my background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm sorry if this was a really simple question but I just got started with HTML and I’m unsure how to make my `li` overlap my original image.

Here is my CSS:

```css
 #myUL li a {
  transform: translate(0px,0px); /* Standard syntax */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}
```

This is the JavaScript:

```js
<script>
var UL = document.getElementById("myUL");
// hilde the list by default
UL.style.display = "none";
var searchBox = document.getElementById("myInput");

// show the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("focus",  function(){
    // UL.style.display = "block";
});



function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    // if the input is empty hide the list
    if(filter.trim().length < 1) {
        ul.style.display = "none";
        return false;
    } else {
        ul.style.display = "block";
    }

    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        // This is when you want to find words that contain the search string
     if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) { 
        li[i].style.display = "";
     } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    } 

</script>
```

The list in the HTML:

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search here.." title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL">
<li><a href="#">    CASCO EDUCATIONAL SUPPLY PTE LTD    01-02   </a></li>
<li><a href="#">    KOPITIAM INVESTMENT PTE LTD 01-04   </a></li>
<li><a href="#">    REGENT IMPEX PTE LTD    02-01   </a></li>
</ul>
```

Original image in the HTML:

```html
<img src="file://C:/Users/MINI PC/Desktop/HTML/HOME.png" width="1080" height="1920" alt="" title="" />
```

Is this enough to find the problems?

Comment: It's impossible to help with CSS without also seeing the HTML. Please post a JSFiddle.

Comment: I have updated the code is it able to see the probem now?

Comment: You have given us Javascript when @Dai asked for HTML... Is that all you have?

Comment: ouh sorry I had updated it. Btw I've updated the code again and this is all my code

Comment: Add you HTML as a whole single block so we can see the order of everything.

Comment: Is there a reason the `img` isn't just a background image at the res `width="1080" height="1920"` that you've set I assume that's what it's doing anyway?